# Visual Studio Code: How to add checkbox in view container

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've been searching non-stop for this on the documentation but haven't been able to find any sort of information. I would like to know how to add checkboxes in my custom view container, similar to the breakpoints' checkboxes.

[image: Checkbox example]

Comment: I think they simulate the checkbox by playing with he icon, create a new treeitem with a different icon when clicked.

Comment: somehow they have knowledge on where on the treeitem you click, looking with the dev tools, it is an `<input type="checkbox"/>`, maybe add a doc feature request to update the TreeView doc on how they implemented the Breakpoint view

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't think it would work like that. But thanks, I might do just that. Meanwhile, I think I'll manage by doing what you said, changing the treeitem to a different icon when clicked.

Comment: @rioV8 you should post your comment as answer, since it helped the OP (who then should accept it). Let's keep a clear Q&A style here.

Comment: @MikeLischke I have added the answer and a feature request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simulate the checkbox by playing with the icon, create a new TreeItem with a different icon when clicked.

Somehow they have knowledge on where on the TreeItem you click.

Looking with the dev tools, it is an `<input type="checkbox"/>`.

This means that you can do more with TreeItems than the docs explain.

Looking at the source code the BreakpointView is not implemented with a TreeItemProvider, it extends the `ViewPane` class and uses some kind of templates to render an item. Beside a checkbox it is also possible to have a combobox (`SelectBox` class).

I have added a [feature request (101175)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101175) to extend the vscode API so extension developers can write Views with ViewItems that have additional UI-Elements like the Breakpoint view.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in the proposed api: [treeItemCheckbox](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.treeItemCheckbox.d.ts) in Insiders v1.72 now and since it is a fairly simple new api I suspect it will be released with Stable 1.72.

You can play with this now, see [using the proposed apis](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api).

Instead of extending `TreeItem` you will extend `TreeItem2` (which extends `TreeItem`) if you want to use checkboxes.  Here is some sample code I put together:

```js
export class TreeTab extends vscode.TreeItem2 {
...

  if (tab.isActive) {
    this.iconPath = new vscode.ThemeIcon("arrow-small-right", new vscode.ThemeColor("tab.unfocusedActiveBackground"));

    this.checkboxState = vscode.TreeItemCheckboxState.Checked;
    // this.checkboxState = {state: vscode.TreeItemCheckboxState.Checked, tooltip: "my nifty checkbox tooltip"};
  }
...
```

and elsewhere in your code if you want to detect when that checkbox is clicked/unclicked:

```js
// use your TreeView variable instead of 'tabView'
// from this.tabView = vscode.window.createTreeView(...);

const checkBoxListener = this.tabView.onDidChangeCheckboxState(async event => {

  // event = {item: Array(n)}, which TreeItem's checkbox was clicked and its state after clicking:0/1 = on/off

  console.log(event); 
});
```

[image: TreeItem checkbox demo]

Comment: Of interest, VSCode 1.80 [issue 116141](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116141): Allow TreeItems to have optional checkboxes